# PHP skip for loop Iteration based on a query result set

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, continue

Lets say for example I have a result set from a MySQL query that has produced values: 3,5,10,11 and so forth...

I would like to iterate through a for loop in PHP but exclude the any iteration that would equal any number in results of my MySQL query.

As it stands I currently have:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++)
{
 if($i == 3 or $i == 5)
 {
   continue;
 }
 //Rest of loop...
```

As you will all appreciate hard coding these values is very time consuming and not very efficient. If any one could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you already fetched all the results of the query at the point you're trying to do this?

Comment: Yes, I have fetched the results at this point. I have contemplated putting them into an array however I'm not sure how to integrate this into the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can gather automatically those values you are currently hard coding, you can use [`in_array($search, $array[, $strict])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Like this :

```
$bypass = array(3, 5);

for($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++)
{
    if( in_array($i, $bypass) )
    {
        continue;
    }

    // rest of the loop
}
```

PS : I prefer much more the "Dont Panic" answer, which doesn't use too many loops. (in_array will loop through the array to find your value). See his answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38880057/3799829

Comment: This covers exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If your query results are returned as an array you can use 
`if(in_array($i, $results))` to do a check of $i against the results

Answer (score 2):

Add your values into an array while you fetch your query results. I used PDO here for example, but you should be able to adapt it to whichever database extension you're using:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    $exclude[$row->value] = true;
    // whatever else you're doing with the query results
}
```

If you use the values as keys in the array of things you want to skip, checking for them in your `for` loop should be more efficient than using `in_array`.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) {
    if (isset($exclude[$i])) continue;
    // rest of loop
```

Comment: Nicest of the answers here, no useless loops

Comment: @Bob0t I appreciate the compliment and the reference.